# Converting std::string to std::vector<char>

Tags: c++

I am using a library which accepts data as a `vector` of `char`s. I need to pass a `string` to the library.

I think about using `std::vector` constructor which accepts iterators to carry out the conversion - but wondered if there is a better way of doing it?

```
/*Note: json_str is of type std::string*/
const std::vector<char> charvect(json_str.begin(), json_str.end());
```

Comment: Are you just curious, or did you actually measure and determine that a significant part of your program is spent on copying strings?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Nope, that's the way to do it, directly initializing the vector with the data from the string.

As @ildjarn points out in his comment, if for whatever reason your data buffer needs to be null-terminated, you need to explicitly add it with `charvect.push_back('\0')`.

Also note, if you want to reuse the buffer, use the `assign` member function which takes iterators.

Comment: Note that if the data needs to be null-terminated, the terminating null will have to be pushed back manually.

Comment: @ildjarn: Good point. However, it would be strange for a data buffer to be null terminated, but you never know...

Comment: Note that since C++11 `std::string` is forced to use null terminated strings in its internal buffer. So that push_back is no longer necessary.

Comment: @Manu343726: It still is. Just because it's mandated to be internally null-terminated doesn't change the fact that the `'\0'` is not part of the string elements. If you iterate over the string, you won't get a `'\0'`.

Comment: I concur about using the vector member function `assign` for setting a new value.  In general, it is best to make use of provided member functions of a class since library developers have the opportunity of optimizing the implementation with the class in mind.

Answer (score 19):

Your method of populating the `vector` is fine -- in fact, it's probably best in most cases.

Just so that you know however, it's not the only way.  You could also simply copy the contents of the `string` in to the `vector<char>`.  This is going to be most useful when you either have a `vector` already instantiated, or if you want to append more data to the end -- or at any point, really.

Example, where `s` is a `std::string` and `v` is a `std::vector<char>`:

```
std::copy( s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

As with the constructor case, if you need a null-terminator then you'll need to push that back yourself:

```
v.push_back('\0');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way.

```
  std::string s = "Hello World!";
    std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (const char &c: v)
        std::cout << c;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that might be worth considering if you need the terminating null is:

```
std::vector<char> charvect(json_str.c_str(), json_str.c_str() + json_str.size() + 1);
```

and if `charvect` already exists you can do:

```
charvect.assign(json_str.c_str(), json_str.c_str() + json_str.size() + 1);
```

This might be quicker than doing a `push_back('\0')` particularly if the push_back triggers a memory reallocation.