# How to copy std::string into std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, string, vector, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting std::string to std::vector<char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247793/converting-stdstring-to-stdvectorchar)

I tried:

```
std::string str = "hello";
std::vector<char> data;
std::copy(str.c_str(), str.c_str()+str.length(), data);
```

but it does not work=( So I wonder How to copy `std::string` into `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<uchar>` ?

Comment: Using the search is helpful, y'know...

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators. You can use that:

```
std::string str = "hello";
std::vector<char> data(str.begin(), str.end());
```

If you already have a vector and want to add the characters at the end, you need a back inserter:

```
std::string str = "hello";
std::vector<char> data = /* ... */;
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
```

Comment: just declare the vector like so std::vector<unsigned char>

Comment: @myWallJSON You mean copying data from a `string` to `vector<unsigned char>`? If there's an implicit conversion between `char` and `unsigned char` (which I think there is, but I'm not sure), then yes, it will work.

Comment: @R.Martinho: I'm pretty certain the reserve is unnecessary because common standard library implementations will dispatch to overloads specializing for random-access iterators so they can employ memmove anyway.

Comment: Will this also copy the null-terminator into the vector?

Comment: @Robert: As is, not. It can be easily modified to do so if necessary, though.

Comment: If one needs to set a new value, I recommend using the vector member function `assign` (with the string's begin and end iterators) rather than the more complicated external copy function. In general, when available it is best to make use of provided member functions of a class since library developers have the opportunity of optimizing the implementation with the class in mind.

Answer (score 10):

You need a back inserter to copy into vectors:

```
std::copy(str.c_str(), str.c_str()+str.length(), back_inserter(data));
```