# How to use multiple times memcpy to convert back a std::vector<unsigned char>?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to convert a set of values which are `strings`, `doubles`, and `time_t` to a `std::vector<unsigned char>` in C++. I am using `memcpy` for that and calling it every time that I have a new value. I just realized that I have to call it backward to concatenate on the right order on my vector. After I convert all my values I want to convert back. The way I am doing is calling each time `memcpy` again to get the original value converted back. But because the values after the first are in the middle of the vector I cannot convert it back properly.

How do I convert back all values from the vector separately? My code is below and the output too. Thanks

```
int main(void) {
    std::string lat = "lat->";
    double latitude = 13.123456;

    std::vector<unsigned char> result(sizeof(lat) + sizeof(latitude));

    std::cout << "copying to the vector" << std::endl;
    memcpy(result.data(), &latitude, sizeof(latitude)); // add string to the vector
    memcpy(result.data(), &lat, sizeof(result.size()) + sizeof(lat)); // add double to the same vector
    std::cout << "copied to the vector\n" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "printing the vector" << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++) {
        std::cout << result[j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "printed the vector\n" << std::endl;

    // testing converting back ...................
    std::cout << "printing back the original value" << std::endl;
    double d;
    std::string value;
    // make sure the vector is the right size
    if (result.size() != (sizeof(d) + sizeof(lat)))
        throw std::runtime_error {
                "Size of data in vector and float do not match" };
    // copy the bytes into the float
    memcpy(&value, result.data(), sizeof(value));
    std::cout << value;
    memcpy(&d, result.data(), sizeof(value) + sizeof(d));
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "printed back the original value\n" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
copying to the vector
copied to the vector

printing the vector
��(�lat->Pş0��(�
printed the vector

printing back the original value
lat->6.95297e-310
printed back the original value

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `string.data()`, you cannot memcpy `std::string` directly

Comment: Your code does nothing of the sort you're thinking it does and contains many errors. I strongly recommend to not attempt byte manipulations like that. They will inevitably fail for types (such as std::string) which may store data on the heap.

Comment: In c++ you only rarely need to use low-level function like `memcpy` (most of the time only if you need to communicate with c apis, or with apis that are close to hardware), so at the point when you use `memcpy` you should think about if you really do the right thing.

Comment: [How to copy std::string into std::vector<char>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263926/how-to-copy-stdstring-into-stdvectorchar)

Comment: @appleapple `memcpy` performs a byte copy. The problem is the types and the sizes not the function. (Although for obvious reasons you don't call memcpy)

Comment: `sizeof(lat)` where `lat` is a `std::string` is unrelated to the data (`"lat->"`) in that string.   Similarly, `sizeof(result)` has no relationship to the number of characters in the vector `result`.   This means you are copying the wrong amount of data with at least some of your calls of `memcpy()`.

Comment: @KostasRim `memcpy` on `string.data()` is fine. (of course need proper size)

Comment: @appleapple the way you wrote it was misleading. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @t.niese - I want to use low level `memcpy` and not `memcpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, don't do that sort of thing unless you know what you're doing (which you didn't).

Writing into the memory buffer:

```
std::string lat = "lat->";
double latitude = 13.123456;

std::vector<unsigned char> result(lat.length() + sizeof(latitude));

std::cout << "copying to the vector" << std::endl;
std::memcpy(result.data(), &latitude, sizeof(latitude));             // add double
std::memcpy(result.data()+sizeof(latitude), lat.data(), lat.size()); // add raw string data
std::cout << "copied to the vector\n" << std::endl;
```

Note that the destination pointer passed to `memcpy` is different for the two calls, pointing each time to memory not previously used.

Care is required when reading back the string with `memcpy`:

```
double d;
std::string value;
std::memcpy(&d, result.data(), sizeof(latitude));    // copy back the bytes of the double
value.resize(lat.length());
std::memcpy(value.data(),result.data()+sizeof(latitude), value.data(), lat.size());
```

You see that we need to know the number of characters (`lat.size()`) before we can copy them from the buffer. This renders the whole approach questionable at best. I strongly recommend that, after understanding this example, you don't do this sort of thing anymore.

Comment: I changed the last `memcpy` to `memcpy(value.data(), result.data() + sizeof(latitude), sizeof(value.data()) + lat.size());`