# how to convert each character in string to ascii value

Tags: c++

I would simply like to convert each character to ascii separated by `x` I would like to have something like `65x122x97x45......`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
std::string text = "This is some text 123...";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could do a join [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430757 ] on a vector [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247793 ]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a magical solution generator

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using stringstreams

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main(){
    std::string text = "This is some text 123...";
    std::istringstream sin(text);
    std::ostringstream sout;
    char temp;
    while(sin>>temp){
        sout<<"x"<<std::hex<<(int)temp;
    }
    std::string output = sout.str();
    std::cout<<output<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
x54x68x69x73x69x73x73x6fx6dx65x74x65x78x74x31x32x33x2ex2ex2e
```