# Converting a string to vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

Is it possible to easily convert a string to a vector in C++?

```
string s = "12345"
vector<int>(s.begin(), s.end(), c => c - '0'); // something like that
```

The goal is to have a vector of ints like `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`

I don't want to use loops, I want to write a clear and simple code. (I know that beneath there will be some loop anyway).

The string is always a number.

Comment: Someone already asked this previosly on StackOverflow, here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247793/converting-stdstring-to-stdvectorchar

Comment: He's converting to a vector of chars, not ints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could start with

```
string s = "12345"
vector<int> v(s.begin(), s.end())
```

and then use `<algorithm>`'s [`transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/):

```
transform(
    s.begin(), s.end(), 
    s.begin(), 
    [](char a){return a - '0';});
```

Comment: oneliner: `transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v),  [](char a){return a - '0'; });`

Comment: I agree. Believe it or not, I started to write this as an alternative, and erased it on the ground that it was not clearer (of course, this is a very personal matter). Perhaps it's good you pointed it out.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly what you want (I don't know how to pull it off in the constructor):

```
string s = "12345";
vector<int> v;
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&v](char c) {v.push_back(c - '0');});
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string gets so long that the performance hit from the double iteration matters, you can also do it in just a single pass:

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(str.size());
transform(begin(str), end(str), back_inserter(v),
    [](const auto &c){return c - '0';});
```

(Or with a C++11 lambda as already shown by others.)

Answer (score 1):

One loop with `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<int> v(s.size());
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin(), [](char c){return c - '0';});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "1234";
vector<int> v;
for(auto& i : s) v.push_back(i - '0');
```

One liner!

Answer (score 0):

Just two lines of mine :

```
vector<int> v(s.begin(), s.end());
for(auto& i : v) i = i - '0';
```

This is simplest one!