# How can I run through a while loop until a new line is reached?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to set a word coming in through std::cin as a vector of chars until a newline ('\n') character is reached. 
Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 


int main(){
std::vector<char> one1; //A char vector that holds the first 'word'
std::cout << "Type in the first set of charactors: " << std::endl;
char o;
std::cin >> o;
int i = 0;
while (std::cin >> o && o != '\n' && o != 0) {
    one1[i] = o;
    i++;
    std::cin >> o;
}
std::cout << "Done"; 

    return 0;
}
```

It keeps returning an error, not a compile error, but during run time, this error comes up:

Debug Assertian Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 
14.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 1234

Expression: vector subscript out of range

I don't know whats wrong, or what is causing this to happen, what should I be doing?

Comment: Why not read string, and then split to chars?

Answer (score 3):

You are reading a character at the end of the loop, and right away another one in the while condition. So every second character gets ignored, you might just miss the `'\n'`.

Also, [] accesses existing elements in the vector, you can't use it to add to it. You need to use `push_back` for that.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior in your code. You access a element that does not exist.

```
std::vector<char> one1;
```

Your vector is empty. As such if you want to add to it you need to use `push_back`:

```
one1.push_back(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to read a line, use the [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function.

Getline stores a line in a string, you then convert that string to a vector ([Converting std::string to std::vector<char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247793/converting-stdstring-to-stdvectorchar))

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Type in the first set of charactors: " << std::endl;
  std::string line;
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  std::vector<char> one1(std::begin(line), std::end(line)); //A char vector that holds the first 'word'
  std::cout << "Done"; 
  return 0;
}
```